# ViewCell.ForceUpdateSize() layout inside appears only after Tap in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got an application with an internal Role system. Based on the current role the user is able to see more settings. For each setting i got a `ViewCell`. So in my case i want to hide the special settings in the beginning and show them if the user has the right to do so.

Unfortunately `ViewCell` doesn't have a Opacity attribute, so i set my `TableView` to `HasUnevenRows="true"` and changed the size of the specific cells to `Height="0"`. Now in code behind, if the User has the right to see the Cell, this is what i call:

```
PumpCell.Height = 42;
PumpCell.ForceUpdateSize();
```

This "unhides" the cell which is exactly what i want to do, but in the first place the Layout inside (I got an `StackLayout` nested inside an `AbsoluteLayout`) is hidden until the Cell is Tapped (see below)

Anyone has an idea to fix this? I even would be fine with manually invoking a Tap on the cell, but i haven't found a way yet to do so.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: If you want add cell in runtime , you could use data-binding and add items to source as you need .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I know this is possible, but i wanted to avoid it

Comment: Why? I think this is the best way .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT To be honest, to avoid writing more code. I like to define my layouts as static as possible in my xamls. But i think in my example this is a framework bug, right? If it's not possible though i will go for adding the cells in runtime

Comment: Try to set the property `IsVisible`

Comment: I tried setting IsVisible on every child layout to true, but unfortunately still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

@Elias Johannes, I think you are using the listview, List view is having the issues while dealing with increase the cell size at runtime. Instead of Listview use the Repeater view.
Here is the link for sample,
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87128/repeaterview

Prepare your datatemplate with the additional settings will be IsVisible=false at initial time and when the user clicks on it, take the current item instance and make it ISVisible=true through binding.

Comment: I'm using TableView, i don't know if ReaperView is a worthy replacement?

Comment: Yes, You can use RepeaterView